# LG Monitor IPS weird font and color?

Tags: fonts, resolution, external-display

Hi here is a picture of how it looks like:

[image: My monitor picture]

It looks like when you user the printer missing ink. Has anyone ever fixed this before?

Comment: If you can screenshot it, its not your monitor. What OS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the resolution of your monitor isn't matching the resolution supplied by your computer, which means there's a scaling algorithm applied. These scaling algorithms aren't perfect, and can result in artifacts like the one you're seeing.

(NB since that's a screenshot, it more likely has to do with the zoom level of your browser. Try hitting Ctrl-0 (control key + zero), which should reset the zoom level.)